# Dúvida de cast ponteiro de struct

Tags: c, cast

Não consigo entender o significado desse `cast`: a função vai executar e retorna um tipo `type_t`, que é um `typedef` para `void*`.

Depois é feito um `cast` para `header_t*`, que é uma `struct`, mas não consigo entender como ocorre este `cast`. Quando faço um `cast` como este, o valor de retorno da função vira um tipo `header_t*`.

Como funciona o `cast` de valores para tipo de dados abstratos?

```
header_t *orig_hole_header = (header_t *)lookup_ordered_array(iterator, heap->index);

u32int orig_hole_pos = (u32int)orig_hole_header;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Em primeiro lugar**

`header_t*` é um apontador para o tipo `header_t`.

**Resposta**

Os apontadores para o tipo void `void*` são apontadores para qualquer tipo. São utilizados quando o programador não sabe qual o tipo de informação que este vai receber. Isto é, se é um `int`, `char`...

Como tal estes podem ser convertidos para qualquer tipo de apontador.

```
int i = 5;
void *p = &i;
*p = 4;//Valor de i agora é 4
```

**Porquê o cast (header_t *) ??**

Por razão nenhuma. Pelos menos em C é possivel fazer cast de `void*` para qualquer tipo de apontador, não acrescentando nenhuma informação necessára ao programador(até dificulta a legibilidade do código), mas em C++ é obrigatório o cast.

**Exemplo de retorno tipo void***

`malloc` o seu retorno é `void*` porque o programador pode definir o que tamanho que desejar, sendo assim não fazia sentido ela possuir um tipo com tamanho definido.

**Problema do cast de funções que retornam void***

Se te esqueceres de incluir o header file `stdlib.h` e chamares a função `malloc` terás problemas pois em C o tipo padrão é `int` sendo assim seria considerado `int malloc()` e o cast apenas esconderia o warning dependendo do compilador.